# F#, Split String and .Net methods

Tags: f#

I'm new to F#. I'm using VS2008 shell and F# interactive.
I try to split a string using "System.String.Split" but then I get the error:
"Split is not a static method"

code example:

```
let Count text =
    let words = System.String.Split [' '] text
    let nWords = words.Length
    (nWords)
```

How do I use the String methods like split in F# ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You call them as instance methods:

```
let Count (text : string) =
  let words = text.Split [|' '|]
  let nWords = words.Length
  (nWords)
```

(Note you need to use `[| |]` because Split takes an array not a list; or, as per Joel Mueller's comment, because Split takes a params array, you can just pass in the delimiters as separate arguments (e.g. `text.Split(' ', '\n')`).)

Comment: Split takes a params array, which means you can pass in an array, or you can simply pass in one or more character literals, without an array. `text.Split ' '` or `text.Split ' ', '\n'` (with or without parens) are perfectly valid.

Comment: @Joel - Your second example doesn't work; it creates a tuple with `'\n'` as the second half.  It does work when called as `text.Split(' ', '\n')`, though.

Comment: @kvb - You're right, I misread the output in FSI. I was surprised when it seemed to work.

Answer (score 6):

The function String.split is now defined in the F# Power Pack. You must add

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll";; 
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility.dll";;
```

See the errata for Expert F#: http://www.expert-fsharp.com/Updates/Expert-FSharp-Errata-Jan-27-2009.pdf

Get FSharp.PowerPack.dll here: http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET member functions:

```ml
let count (text : string) =
  text.Split [|' '|]
  |> Seq.length
```

Or using [`FSharpx`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras), which gives us more ergonomic free-functions...

**`paket.dependencies`**

```
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

nuget FSharpx.Extras 2.3.2
```

**`paket.references`**

```
FSharpx.Extras
```

Usage:

```ml
open FSharpx

let count (text : string) =
  text
  |> String.splitChar [| ' ' |]
  |> Seq.length
```

Note that [F# Power Pack seems to be deprecated](https://github.com/fsprojects/zzarchive-powerpack).

Comment: FSharpx wasn’t working for me (with Fable). I’m now using `String.split` from the excellent FSharpPlus project: https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/reference/fsharpplus-string.html#split